# Load templates with the statement {% use %} dynamically in twig symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm doing a project in symfony and I would like to load a template with the use statement.

This is what I like to do:

```
{% for p in db.page. %}
    {% use 'PageBundle:Pages:' ~ p.template ~ '.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

But don't allow it. Returns the following error message:

> The template references in a "use" statement must be a string

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work using include

```
{% for p in db.page %}
    {% include 'PageBundle:Pages:' ~ p.template ~ '.html.twig' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using Twig Use function can export blocks to current template but using Include just print all blocks sequentally.

Answer (score 2):

Twig's **use** function cannot being called using dynamic variables or expressions like OP.

> [**Twig Documentation says:**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html) Because use statements are resolved independently of the context
>   passed tothe  template, the template reference cannot be an
>   expression.

Refer to this link for more info: [Twig Issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/877)